# Javascript function doesn't work after adding content dynamically through ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a function

```
function reply(id) {
        $('#reply_'+id).toggle();
        return false;
    }
```

And Ajax function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function post()
{
  var comment = document.getElementById("comment").value;
  var course_id = document.getElementById("course_id").value;
  var user_id = document.getElementById("user_id").value;
  if(comment)
  {
    $.ajax
    ({
      type: 'post',
      url: 'comments.php',
      data: 
      {
         comment:comment,
         course_id:course_id,
         user_id:user_id
      },
      success: function (response) 
      {
        document.getElementById("comment-list").innerHTML=response+document.getElementById("comment-list").innerHTML;
        document.getElementById("comment").value="";

      }
    });
  }

  return false;
}
</script>
```

And the content that is added after ajax call

```
...
...
 <p class="text-right"><a href="#" onclick="return reply(<?php echo $i; ?>);" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-reply"></i> reply</a></p>    
...
...
<div class="row" id="reply_<?php echo $i; ?>" style="display: none;">
...
...
```

**So basically that javascript functions toggle the div and it is working perfectly fine on page refresh but when adding through ajax success call the javascript toggle doesn't work.** It will work after I refresh the page.

Anyway to fix this so toggle work when content added through ajax without refresh.

Thanks.

Comment: check for ids those should be unique for each element.

Comment: they are. As I said. it works when page refresh but doesnt when added through ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your content that is added after ajax call as below:

```
<p class="text-right">
<a href="#" data-id="<?php echo $i; ?>" class="btn btn-default btn-sm btnReply">
<i class="fa fa-reply"></i> reply</a></p>
```

and write jquery code as below

```
$("body").on("click", ".btnReply", function(event){
   var id =$(this).attr('data-id');
   reply(id);
});
```

Comment: Ok toggle works but the problem is now when I click button it goes to top of page and I have to scroll down to see. Earlier the page stayed where it was.

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript">
$("body").on("click", ".btnReply", function(event){
   var id =$(this).attr('data-id');
   reply(id);
});
 function reply(id) {
  $('#reply_'+id).toggle();
  return false;
 }
</script>`

Comment: <p class="text-right"><a href="#" data-id="<?php echo $i; ?>" class="btn btn-default btn-sm btnReply"><i class="fa fa-reply"></i> reply</a></p>

Comment: <p class="text-right">
<button data-id="<?php echo $i; ?>" class="btn btn-default btn-sm btnReply">
<i class="fa fa-reply"></i> reply
</button>
</p>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137620/discussion-between-yasin-patel-and-phoenix).